# Android Drawing a Smooth Path

Tags: android, drawing

I have code that I need to improve.

Here's what's wrong: it's a little slow and choppy, meaning the lines aren't smooth and the drawing is a bit delayed.

```
public void touchStarted(Point point) {
    if (null == drawingModePath) {
        drawingModePath = new Path();
    }
    drawingModePath.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
}


public void touchMoved(Point point) {
    drawingModePath.lineTo(point.x, point.y);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
                .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    mainDrawingView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    // Path

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawPath(drawingModePath, paint);
}

public void touchEnded(Point point) {
        touchMoved(point);
}
```

In essence what this code does is drawing a path based on touchStarted, touchMoved, and touchEnded. If someone can help me optimize this, I'd be grateful. Perhaps if I don't recreate the bitmap each time touchMoved occurs? Not sure here... not sure... I use a UIBezierPath to perform this code on iOS and it's a bit faster (and smoother). Anyway, I come to you for help. Input appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are recreating everything every move. that will affect the performance of drawing a lot. the event triggers every 8ms (or 16ms im not sure), imagine you are reinstantiating everything every 8ms? thats tough.

**so this must be in the instantiation part**

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
mainDrawingView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
```

**The `touchMoved()` should only record the new path and call the invalidate() to make the View redraw itself resulting in calling the draw method (`onDraw()`).**

```
public void touchMoved(Point point) {
    drawingModePath.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
    invalidate();
}
```

**and then implement `onDraw()` method to do the drawing**

Heres how i do the drawing interface in one of my projects:

```
public class SignatureView extends View {

    public SignatureView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // instantiating my paint object
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        path = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld)
    {
        // this is where i initialize my canvas, because in constructor, the view is not completely instantiated yet, so getting the height and width there will result in null exception.
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(xNew, yNew, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        background_canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        // draw the new path to a buffer canvas 
        background_canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        // put the buffer in the real canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {

        //this is like your move event, it just records the new path every move.
        int action = ev.getActionMasked();
        if ( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN )
        {
            path.moveTo(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
        }
        else if ( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE )
        {
            path.lineTo(ev.getX(), ev.getY());
            // call invalidate() to make the view redraw itself, resulting in calling the onDraw() method.
            invalidate();
        }
        else if ( action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP )
        {
            onDone.method();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        background_canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    interface OnDone{
        void method();
    }

    public void setOnDone(OnDone new_onDone)
    {
        onDone = new_onDone;
    }

    OnDone onDone;
    private Paint paint;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Canvas background_canvas;
    private Path path;
    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```